# GraphQL throwing syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am developing the GraphQL Node tutorial, and am up to step 7.

https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/7-subscriptions/

I am getting a number of syntax errors from this code in my `datamodel.prisma` file:

```
directive @id on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @unique on FIELD_DEFINITION
directive @createdAt on FIELD_DEFINITION
scalar DateTime

type Link {
    id: ID! @id
    createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
    description: String!
    url: String!
    postedBy: User
    votes: [Vote!]!
}

type User {
    id: ID! @id
    name: String!
    email: String! @unique
    password: String!
    links: [Link!]!
    votes: [Vote!]!
}

type Vote {
    id: ID! @id
    link: Link!
    user: User!
}
```

But am still getting `'User' type [@6:1] tried to redefine existing 'User' type [@15:5]` and `'Link' type [@24:1] tried to redefine existing 'Link' type [@6:5]`.

I am also not sure if I am declaring `directives` or `scalars` correctly as this is missing from the official tutorial.

Can anyone give any advice on how to sort these issues?

Schema.graphql:

```
type Query {
    info: String!
    feed(filter: String, skip: Int, first: Int, orderBy: LinkOrderByInput): Feed!
}

type Feed {
    links: [Link!]!
    count: Int!
}

type AuthPayload {
    token: String
    user: User
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    links: [Link!]!
}

type Vote {
    id: ID!
    link: Link!
    user: User!
}

type Link {
    id: ID!
    description: String!
    url: String!
    postedBy: User
    votes: [Vote!]!
}

type Subscription {
    newLink: Link
    newVote: Vote
}

type Mutation {
    post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
    signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): AuthPayload
    login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
    vote(linkId: ID!): Vote
}

enum LinkOrderByInput {
    description_ASC
    description_DESC
    url_ASC
    url_DESC
    createdAt_ASC
    createdAt_DESC
}
```

Comment: If you remove directive and scalar lines, does it work?

Comment: What is your actual schema look like? Are you importing the generated Prisma types into it?

Comment: @TarunLalwani if I remove those lines I get many more syntax errors, I think they are required?

Comment: @DanielRearden I have added the schema.graphql file above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error this morning and I have a feeling it has something to do with caching. It went away when I renamed the variable.  In your case, change all 'Link' definition/references to 'LinkTwo' and see if the error goes away. Same with 'User'... change it to 'UserTwo'.  If it does, perhaps you can rename them back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Prisma before and only glanced at the tutorial but it looks like you're defining two User types; you have one in datamodel.prisma and Schema.graphql (I couldn't find two definitions of User in the tutorial). If they are read into the same instance, that'll be the reason why graphql thinks you are trying to redefine the User type. Remove one or, if it's applicable, change the second to `extend type User` should solve the syntax error.